# How to reset values after dying

Tags: c++, sdl, reset

I am making a google chrome dinosaur game using an SDL Template for graphics and I am almost finished but I have run into the issue of needing to be able to reset to the starting values of the game just like how you reset when you hit spacebar after dying in the google chrome dinosaur game. I have made an isGameOver function but I don't know how to reset the values to start a new game which is my main problem.

this is my GameScene class where the game over logic is located

GameScene.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Scene.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Floor.h"
#include "Obstacle.h"
#include "FlyingObstacle.h"
#include <vector>
#include "util.h"
#include "text.h"

class GameScene : public Scene
{
public:
    GameScene();
    ~GameScene();
    void start();
    void draw();
    void update();
    std::vector<Obstacle*> spawnedObstacle;
    std::vector<FlyingObstacle*> spawnedBird;

private:
    Player* player;
    Floor* floor;

    float spawnTime;
    float currentSpawnTimer;
    void floorCollision();
    void obstacleCollision();
    void birdCollision();
    void obstacleSpawn();
    void birdSpawn();
    void despawnObstacle(Obstacle* obstacle);
    void despawnBird(FlyingObstacle* bird);
    int points;
    int highscore;
    bool isGameOver;
};
```

GameScene.cpp

```
#include "GameScene.h"

GameScene::GameScene()
{
    // Register and add game objects on constructor
    player = new Player();
    this->addGameObject(player);

    floor = new Floor();
    this->addGameObject(floor);

    points = 0;
    highscore = 0;

}

GameScene::~GameScene()
{
    delete player;
}

void GameScene::start()
{
    Scene::start();
    // Initialize any scene logic here

    initFonts();
    isGameOver = true;
    currentSpawnTimer = 300;
    spawnTime = rand() % 300; //spawn time of 5 seconds

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {

        obstacleSpawn();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        birdSpawn();
    }


}

void GameScene::draw()
{
    Scene::draw();

        drawText(110, 20, 255, 255, 255, TEXT_CENTER, "POINTS: %03d", points);


        if (player->getIsAlive() == true)
        {
            drawText(900, 20, 255, 255, 255, TEXT_CENTER, "PRESS SPACE TO START MOVING");
        }

    if (player->getIsAlive() == false)
    {
        if (isGameOver == false)

        drawText(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 200, 255, 255, 255, TEXT_CENTER, "YOU LOSE! PRESS SPACE TO SHOW POINTS");

        if (isGameOver == true)
        {
            drawText(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 200, 255, 255, 255, TEXT_CENTER, "HIGHSCORE: %03d", highscore); 

                if (points > highscore)
                {
                    drawText(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 200, 255, 255, 255, TEXT_CENTER, "NEW HIGHSCORE: %03d", points, highscore);
                }
        }
    }
}

void GameScene::update()
{

    if (isGameOver == true)
    {
        if (app.keyboard[SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE])
        {
            isGameOver = false;
            
        }

    }
    if (isGameOver == false)
    {
        Scene::update();

        floorCollision();
        obstacleCollision();
        birdCollision();


        if (currentSpawnTimer > 0)
            currentSpawnTimer--;

        if (currentSpawnTimer <= 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                obstacleSpawn();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                birdSpawn();
            }

            currentSpawnTimer = spawnTime;
        }
        //This is where Gravity strength is located
        if (player->getOnFloor() == false) {
            player->setY(player->getY() + 7);
        }

        else {
            player->getY() + 0;
        }
    }
}



void GameScene::floorCollision()
{
        //Checks for collisions
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
        {
            //Cast to floor
            Floor* floor = dynamic_cast<Floor*>(objects[i]);

            //Check if the floor was casted
            if (floor != NULL)
            {

                int collision = checkCollision(
                    player->getX(), player->getY(), player->getWidth(), player->getHeight(),
                    floor->getX(), floor->getY(), floor->getWidth(), floor->getHeight()
                );

                if (collision == 1)
                {

                    player->setOnFloor(true);
                    
                    if (player->getIsAlive() == true)
                    {
                        points++;
                        highscore++;
                    }

                    break;
                }

            }
        }
}


void GameScene::obstacleCollision()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
    {

        Obstacle* obstacle = dynamic_cast<Obstacle*>(objects[i]);

        if (obstacle != NULL)
        {
            if (obstacle != NULL)
            {
                int collision = checkCollision(
                    player->getX(), player->getY(), player->getWidth(), player->getHeight(),
                    obstacle->getX(), obstacle->getY(), obstacle->getWidth(), obstacle->getHeight()
                );

                if (collision == 1)
                {
                    player->doDeath();
                    isGameOver = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

void GameScene::birdCollision()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
    {

        FlyingObstacle* bird = dynamic_cast<FlyingObstacle*>(objects[i]);


        if (bird != NULL)
        {
            if (bird != NULL)
            {
                int collision = checkCollision(
                    player->getX(), player->getY(), player->getWidth(), player->getHeight(),
                    bird->getX(), bird->getY(), bird->getWidth(), bird->getHeight()
                );

                if (collision == 1)
                {
                    player->doDeath();
                    isGameOver = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


void GameScene::obstacleSpawn()
{
    Obstacle* obstacle = new Obstacle();
    this->addGameObject(obstacle);

    obstacle->setPosition(1200, 300 + (rand() % 300));
    spawnedObstacle.push_back(obstacle);
}

void GameScene::birdSpawn()
{
    FlyingObstacle* bird = new FlyingObstacle();
    this->addGameObject(bird);

    bird->setPos(1200, 300 + (rand() % 300));
    spawnedBird.push_back(bird);
}

void GameScene::despawnObstacle(Obstacle* obstacle)
{
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnedObstacle.size(); i++)
    {
        //If pointer matches
        if (obstacle == spawnedObstacle[i])
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //If any match is found
    if (index != -1)
    {
        spawnedObstacle.erase(spawnedObstacle.begin() + index);
        delete obstacle;
    }
}

void GameScene::despawnBird(FlyingObstacle* bird)
{
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < spawnedBird.size(); i++)
    {
        //If pointer matches
        if (bird == spawnedBird[i])
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //If any match is found
    if (index != -1)
    {
        spawnedBird.erase(spawnedBird.begin() + index);
        delete bird;
    }
}
```

I tried making an isGameOver bool inside my GameScene.h and I made it so that pressing spacebar would reset the game but in reality when the player dies the screen pauses every movement instead of resetting and if I press space again the game continues to move even though the player is dead.

Comment: OT: `isGameOver = true;` in the **`start`** functions seems wrong.

Comment: As for your problem, use a loop in the `main` function. When the game is over you destroy all objects and resources, basically what you would do when you exit the program. But instead of exiting the program you iterate the loop and create a brand new game.

Comment: wait sorry what do you mean by main function? like at GameScene update?

Comment: No, in the actual `main` function. Instead of initializing the game, running the game loop, and cleaning up before exit only once, you put all those parts into a loop. Like (***pseudo-code***) `while (continue_game) { game_setup(); game_main_event_loop(); game_teardown(); }`. Add a check if the user want's to run again after teardown but before end of loop.

Comment: Since your question does not concern the time when the game is player, you could replace the code related to playing the game with `/* Play the game */` and drastically reduce the size of your [mre]. Think of it this way: pretend the game ends in a loss as soon as it starts, and at that point you want to reset (which is the subject of your question). How much code does it take to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entry point for the game(probably `main`)function will probably have some form like this

```
#include ...
#include ...
...

int main()
{
   bool game_running = true;
   while(game_running)
   {
       GameInstance* game = new Game(); //Allocation and initialization of all resources needed to play the game.
       game.play(); // This function will finish when you lose the game.
       delete game; // Deallocation.
       if(!run_again())
       {
           game_running = false;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

After deallocation, you check if user wants to play again, you enter the next iteration of `while` loop, and new instance of `Game` is allocated, where all the resource handling takes place. The only problem is that allocating `Game` instance for every iteration might be a little costly, but you can ignore that if you don't worry about performance much.